# How to apply Recursive data in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, recursive-datastructures

I am working with the reporting services, I have a report like the attached photo.

[image]

The last column(`Balance`) is a calculated column.

So if it is the first row, show the initial value

Else: return the previous `Balance + In - Out`.

I am not sure if reporting services support something like that? Are you able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RunningValue function.

Your expression should look like `=RunningValue(Fields!balance.Value + Fields!invalue.Value - Fields!outvalue.Value, SUM, Nothing)`

In case there is a group in your report eg. by account you should replace Nothing with your group name eg. `=RunningValue(Fields!balance.Value + Fields!invalue.Value - Fields!outvalue.Value, SUM, "account")`

[image]

[image]

For more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function

Comment: Nice to know it helped you